# Does SemaphoreSlim(1, 1) ensures read and writes are flushed from caches like lock?

Tags: c#, race-condition

## Extra question

Does `SemaphoreSlim(1, 1)` still ensures that I have the correct output 1000000, even if `task1` and `task2` run on 2 different cores?

## Original question

Considering the following code snippet, does the `_semaphore` has the same effect as `lock`?

The outputs:

1. using lock: 1000000
2. `_semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1)`: 1000000 (I run the program 10 times and the results are the same)
3. `_semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(10, 10)`: varies from 999998 to 999990 to 1000000, etc.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Calculate
    {
        private int _val = 0;
        private object _addLock = new object();
        private SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
        public int Val
        {
            get
            {
                return _val;
            }
        }

        public void IncreManyTimes()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 500000; ++i)
            {
                //lock(_addLock)
                //{
                //    _val = _val + 1;
                //}
                _semaphore.Wait();
                _val = _val + 1;
                _semaphore.Release();
            }
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Calculate calculate = new Calculate();
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Task task1 = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    calculate.IncreManyTimes();
                });

                Task task2 = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    calculate.IncreManyTimes();
                });
                Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
            }).Wait();
           
            Console.WriteLine(calculate.Val);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The related question: [Does locking ensure reads and writes are flushed from caches? If so, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833462/does-locking-ensure-reads-and-writes-are-flushed-from-caches-if-so-how)

And my question could be described as:  Does `SemaphoreSlim(1, 1)` ensure reads and writes are flushed from caches?

Comment: You might find interesting: [Memory barrier generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581848/memory-barrier-generators). Also this: [Does SemaphoreSlim (.NET) prevent same thread from entering block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985233/does-semaphoreslim-net-prevent-same-thread-from-entering-block)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thanks for the information. Could you please also provide links illustrating race condition happening in multi cpu cores? I'm afraid whether my example still give the correct output if `task1` and `task2` run on different cores.

Comment: Tomingsun I can't find any questions related to thread-safety and multiprocessor hardware. Also I have no personal experience with such systems, so I can't offer credible advice about them. My assumption is that the `lock` should work just as well on multiprocessor systems as on multi-core single-processor systems. But this is just an assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters in the semaphoreslim specify how many threads can operate concurrently and what the initial count is. If you want to use semaphoreslim as the equivalent of the c# lock statement, then the number of supported threads **must** be one. When you initialize your sempahore with 10, you're saying that up to 10 threads can execute at the same time, which is not the same thing as a lock.

Semaphore has nothing to do with flushing reads or writes, to that is entirely based on how you use the semaphore.

If you're going to use it as a lock, you need to be sure that every time the semaphore is waited, it is also released, so use a try/finally block.

Comment: To be short, in my specific case, `SemaphoreSlim(1, 1)` works **just like** `lock`, even if `task1` and `task2` run on 2 different cpu cores?

Comment: Yes, the semaphoreslim does not have thread affinity.

Answer (score 4):

> does the `_semaphore` has the same effect as `lock`?

Yes and no. Considering the behavior of your `IncreManyTimes` method it has the same effect indeed (`_val = _val + 1;` will not run concurrently by multiple threads).

They have some differences, though. For example, `lock` is always dedicated to its executing thread, whereas the `SemaphoreSlim` can be released from any thread. That's why a `SemaphoreSlim` is a good alternative for 'locking' around a code block that contains an `await` (which wouldn't even compile with `lock` because it would not work as intended if the continuation executes on a different thread).

As a further note, if there is an exception inside the `lock`, the lock is released. To achieve the same effect you must put your `_semaphore.Release();` in a `finally` block.

Additionally, the `SemaphorSlim` is a disposable object so you should consider implementing `IDisposable` in your `Calculate` class.

And finally, I don't know if this is just a simplified example but here you don't need any of those. You can increment simply by `Interlocked.Increment(ref _val)`, which does not need locking.

**Edit:**

> Does `SemaphoreSlim(1, 1)` still ensures that I have the correct output 1000000, even if `task1` and `task2` run on 2 different cpu cores?

Yes, because it allows only one thread in the critical section at once.

Comment: Thanks, and it is a simplified situation. Could please have a look at my **Extra question** too?